# dc.js reduce space/padding inside svg element

Tags: d3.js, svg, dc.js

I have a chart in dc.js (which uses d3.js).

I need to snug up my SVG chart within the div container and I notice there is some white space inside the SVG element - between the SVG element and g elements within.

Note that in this stack snippet example (and in [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/koap7Lj5/)) there is an inner svg element (**svg>svg>g**), but in my live code there is only one svg element before the g elements (**svg>g**).

How can I style the chart to remove that white space immediately inside the outer svg container? *(In the example below, I wish to remove the empty space between the green and red lines.)*

```js
var myCSV = [
 {"shift":"1","date":"01/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"178","truck":"255","bike":"17","moto":"7"},
 {"shift":"2","date":"01/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"125","truck":"189","bike":"45","moto":"3"},
 {"shift":"3","date":"02/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"140","truck":"219","bike":"28","moto":"12"},
 {"shift":"4","date":"02/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"222","truck":"290","bike":"32","moto":"8"},
 {"shift":"5","date":"03/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"200","truck":"250","bike":"20","moto":"19"},
 {"shift":"6","date":"03/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"230","truck":"220","bike":"10","moto":"13"},
];

lc1 = dc.lineChart("#line1");

var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y/%H/%M/%S");

myCSV.forEach(function (d) {
 d.date = dateFormat.parse(d.date);
});

var facts = crossfilter(myCSV);
var dateDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d.date});

var carDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d['car']});
var dgCar = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {return d['car']});

var minDate = new Date ("2016-01-01T08:00:00.000Z");
var maxDate = new Date ("2016-01-03T17:00:00.000Z"); 

var maxY = d3.max(myCSV, function(d) {return d['car']});

lc1
.renderArea(false)
.width(300)
.height(250)
.dimension(dateDim)
.group(dgCar)
.defined(function(d) {if(d.y !==null) {return d.y;}})
.transitionDuration(1000)
.margins({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 60})
.yAxisLabel('Cars')
.renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
.brushOn(false)
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]));
lc1.yAxis().ticks(5);
lc1.xAxis().ticks(3);

dc.renderAll();
dc.redrawAll();
```

```css
svg{height:280px;}
#msg{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;padding:5px;}
svg{outline:1px solid green;}
svg>svg{outline:1px solid red;}
svg>g{outline:1px solid gold;}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.1/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>
<link href="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<svg id="line1"></svg>
```

Comment: Decrease the height of the svg from 280px to some smaller number.

Comment: Probably the margins you set above? http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.marginMixin.html

Comment: @Gordon That was exactly it Gordon, thank you. Sometimes I can't see what's right in front of my eyes (or, fall prey to Clarke's third law).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decrease the size of your margins and increase the height of the inner svg (to match the outer svg), it snugs up nicely:

```js
var myCSV = [
 {"shift":"1","date":"01/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"178","truck":"255","bike":"17","moto":"7"},
 {"shift":"2","date":"01/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"125","truck":"189","bike":"45","moto":"3"},
 {"shift":"3","date":"02/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"140","truck":"219","bike":"28","moto":"12"},
 {"shift":"4","date":"02/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"222","truck":"290","bike":"32","moto":"8"},
 {"shift":"5","date":"03/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"200","truck":"250","bike":"20","moto":"19"},
 {"shift":"6","date":"03/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"230","truck":"220","bike":"10","moto":"13"},
];

lc1 = dc.lineChart("#line1");

var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y/%H/%M/%S");

myCSV.forEach(function (d) {
 d.date = dateFormat.parse(d.date);
});

var facts = crossfilter(myCSV);
var dateDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d.date});

var carDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d['car']});
var dgCar = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {return d['car']});

var minDate = new Date ("2016-01-01T08:00:00.000Z");
var maxDate = new Date ("2016-01-03T17:00:00.000Z"); 

var maxY = d3.max(myCSV, function(d) {return d['car']});

lc1
.renderArea(false)
.width(300)
.height(280)
.dimension(dateDim)
.group(dgCar)
.defined(function(d) {if(d.y !==null) {return d.y;}})
.transitionDuration(1000)
.margins({top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 27})
.yAxisLabel('Cars')
.renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
.brushOn(false)
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]));
lc1.yAxis().ticks(5);
lc1.xAxis().ticks(3);

dc.renderAll();
dc.redrawAll();
```

```css
svg{height:280px;}
#msg{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;padding:5px;}
svg{outline:1px solid green;}
svg>svg{outline:1px solid red;}
svg>g{outline:1px solid gold;}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.1/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>
<link href="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<svg id="line1"></svg>
```